# How different is the induced magnetic field of a coil with a solid rod core and a sheet-wrapped one? (Assuming both use the same material)

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I'm doing research for a university project and looking for commercial references for Mu metal, I found out that in my country at P2B (particular to business) level, sheets are significantly easier to acquire than solid rods, so getting a valid invoice for tax purposes is easier if my company purchases a sheet spool.

Then, my main question would be regarding the mathematics of the wrapped-sheet core: how differently does the magnetic field travel through a continuous but layered core, how different would be the magnetization curve in relation to its solid rod counterpart, to what extent does having slack will affect its performance, how is inductance affected... I already have matlab code to calculate the parameters for a solid rod core, but having the latter much easier to access for my company is more important at this particular moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The sheet used for transformer core laminations is magnetically anisotropic because the rolling process used to flatten the sheet imprints anisotropy on the microstructure of the metal alloy itself. This makes the laminations harder to magnetically saturate and thereby increases the performance of the core.

In addition, the electrical resistance in a laminated core is also strongly anisotropic in the sheet-to-sheet direction relative to the along-the-length direction, which minimizes eddy current losses in the core.

Note that core lamination sheet is *not* ordinary steel or iron, it is a special steel alloy with significant additions of silicon and other stuff to the mix which makes for a superior product and is readily available commercially... and not particularly expensive compared to its improved performance. It is therefore universally used to manufacture transformer cores.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Do you know of any literature i can use to back it up formally? Also regarding the magnetic properties, wouldn't there be a higher coercive field? That would be a bit problematic for me since said coils have to be quickly demagnetized, and also how will affect the lamination to the coil behavior if actuated using a PWM signal? Dk if by applying certain frequencies the core would start resonating and making the whole contraption unpredictable

Comment: @murisio, you're describing an entire field of electrical engineering. You'd be far better off bringing in someone from a transformer manufacturer and getting a tutorial, and leaving the design & construction to them.